# MySQL Cursor unable to pick the fetch variable

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am writing a cursor to loop through all the tables in MySQL schema and get the actual maximum column size of each columns. Below is the cursor I have written for it. But I'm unable to loop through the tables and select the result set:

```
DELIMITER // 

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_test //

 CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test ()

BEGIN
   DECLARE exit_loop BOOLEAN;   
   DECLARE mycol VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE mytab VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
SELECT column_name,table_name FROM information_Schema.columns where table_schema='TestDB' ;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop = TRUE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp ( colsize int, colname varchar(1000));
OPEN cur1;
read_loop: LOOP
FETCH cur1 INTO mycol,mytab;
INSERT INTO temp (colname,tabname)
select MAX(OCTET_LENGTH(mycol)),IC.column_name from mytab  inner join information_Schema.columns IC on IC.column_name= mycol;
     IF exit_loop THEN
     CLOSE cur1;
     LEAVE read_loop;
 END IF;
   END LOOP read_loop;
 select count(*) from temp;
END;
//
call sp_test
```

This code throws error: Table TestDB.mytab doesn't exist. I'm unable to pass the value i get from the cursor to the variable or i'm using it incorrectly. If I just use the select instead of INSERT INTO temp table i'm seeing multiple result set for each loop. Please correct me in order to achieve my use case.

Thank you

Comment: select MAX(OCTET_LENGTH(mycol)),IC.column_name from mytab  inner join information_Schema.columns IC on IC.column_name= mycol;
 
CHeck the table mytab,does it exists in your db?

Comment: No, it's not table name. it is the fetch variable I use to load all the table names in my MYSQL database: FETCH cur1 INTO mycol,mytab;

Comment: @ksl123 but i'm unable to pass the value of the variables, I dont understand what mistake I'm doing

Comment: Use [13.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: i understood that you are fetching into mycol,mytab.But you are using 'mytab' in the select statement of insert

Comment: Are you aware of [SELECT ... PROCEDURE ANALYSE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/procedure-analyse.html) which does exactly what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wchiquito mentioned you need to use prepared SQL statement which will take the below statement as string and execute it. Because while executing a statement mysql won't retrieve the value before executing it so we need to prepare a dynamic string and execute it,

```
SET @toExec := CONCAT('INSERT INTO temp (colname,tabname) select MAX(OCTET_LENGTH(',mycol,')),IC.column_name from ',mytab,'  inner join information_Schema.columns IC on IC.column_name= ''',mycol,'''');
PREPARE stmt3 FROM @toExec;
EXECUTE stmt3;
```

Hope it helps!